# Is there an issue posting your own for-sale add-on as an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

I have recently created an add-on, which is for sale on the Blender Market, that I think answers a question by a user on the main part of site. (A question that doesn't yet have an accepted answer).

Are there any guidelines as to whether I should or how I should proceed with an answer that features an add-on that is for sale without it seeming like an advert for my own product?

I don't want to come across as self-promoting, but the answer would inevitably drive traffic to a product and potentially drive up sales.

I will of course provide a link to the product and the question I think it answers if required, but I thought that even mentioning the add-on here on the meta might come across as promotion.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is ok to post an answer that uses a product you made or are affiliated with, when it *does* answer the question, and only if you disclose your affiliation.
I would caution you that it will not get UVed as much (because it is a paid addon), and possibility DVed. However there is nothing wrong (when following the guidelines) with you linking to your addon.

Think of it this way, I right an answer that uses your addon, or any other program or service; and there is nothing wrong with me linking to the tool(s) I use. In the same way, the creator of the tool is not outright banned from mentioning it.

The SE help pages have this to say.

> **Avoid overt self-promotion.**
>
> The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.
>
> If a large percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details. We also offer free community promotion ads for open source projects and non-profit organizations.

<sup>taken from https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/behavior</sup>

[Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57497/278094) and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140402/278094) are good overviews of SE's position.