# I see soo many questions, low views, and almost no answers

Tags: discussion

Title explains it.

Weird, right?

Comment: PS please never write a question with the body "Title says it." or such.

Comment: I do my best as I can answer some questions (I've been learning Blender for 4 years), but often the question is very badly formulated, or doesn't give enough details, or no screenshot, rarely any file... even after several demands, so people should make sure that their question is clear and simple

Comment: also it looks like a lot of people who don't know anything about bones and rigging use pre-made armatures or pre-rigged characters and want them to be fixed, I don't think it's the right way to help... Also very large questions like: after rigging my mesh is completely messy, it's obvious that some people have not even followed tutorials on the topic and it can't be summed in three lines...

Answer (score 11):

**WTL:DR**  yep same problem on nearly every site, need more users to do all the other things (like answer).

Not weird. It's sad but, normal. You can look at any SE site and see the same content decline. (Its a big problem).
However here on BSE it's more pronounced. Why? Because we have *many, Many* new blender users. They only come here when they get stuck in a tutorial, or when their import fails. They do not (at the start) want to answer any questions, and in many cases they do not know enough to answer.

So, many brand new blender (and SE) users hits at both ends of the problem. They ask lots of questions (more on that in a bit), and they do not care to look around, and do not know blender enough to answer.

Now what about the rest of us that have rep? (*hooray for useless internet points*) Sure we may view the questions, even answer some every day. But there is simply not enough of us to answer. We get about **40** questions per day. I simply do not have time to read all of them. (Back in the day I use to go through every new question that was asked... but I digress)
Now what lies in these many questions? Looking at the top 30 newest questions [right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPff7.png) there are **8** answered, and **1** UVed. Out of **thirty**.

No UVs could mean low quality posts, again a common problem with new users.
There being more answers then votes means either people are not voting on the questions (a couple of reasons for that), or the people getting to these questions can not vote on them (less then 15 rep).

The not voting could be because it is a new user and we want to be "welcoming" and not DV their post. Or it is not quite bad enough to DV, but it sure is not UV worthy.

The other reason for the more answers then votes, could be because there are new users answering them (because they all need more rep).

---

#### What can we do about it?

Good question. There is no "quick fix". In fact there is no solution. As long as there is an influx of new users we will have a huge question gap (and quality issue).
So tell everbody you know that knows blender to get over here and help this site out.
We need people to answer question.
We need the people to write the comments to the new users saying "we need more information, to be able to answer your question."
We need people to find the duplicates (there are LOTS). 
As someone coined it we need more "curators."

<sup><sub>Wow that turned out long.</sub></sup>

Comment: Plus, with the insane policies being put in place, I don't want to risk being "offensive" in an answer or comment -

Comment: Any SE site except for *interpersonal*, they literally have no [unanswered questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5svHO.png). It is probably the most successful network on SE.

Answer (score 7):

Another important point is that everyone answering questions is doing so on their own time, out of the goodness of their heart, to help people.  It takes time.  Often times, answering a question means opening Blender, adjusting settings or doing some light modeling, perhaps rendering, and taking a bunch of screenshots.  It can take 30 minutes to an hour to answer a single question depending on the complexity.  Most of us have jobs, families, and other things to do besides answer Blender questions, so we have to find the time.  The only reward is reputation points, and many times people don't even "accept" the answer as correct so there's no reputation reward, only knowing you helped someone.

TL;DR - it takes time, expertise, and can be thankless, so there aren't enough people able and willing to do it.

Comment: Truly have nothing to add, except that your points are true. It's how it is. Imagine a different situation where the community is so well known amongst each other, and everybody usually know what theyr doing, it would probably bring more help in need as it acts as one, lets just call it 'family'. But like this, one just doesnt have enough time to take care of those massive amounts of questions, speacialy being asked mostly in the way you brought up in the comments above.

Comment: As for tbe newbies (im no pro in blender to make it clear), i only recently have become familiar with it. BUT, from the another field of creativity from which i come, i do know a fact that you best learn by trial and error, and errors will come in giant waves as you (they) go. Yes tutorials and help comes extra handy specialy in this time when there are lot lf thing to be done in shorter amount of time, but tou really absorb material when you actually 'get burned', when you hit the error. Time go ahead, and methods kinda stay the same, just that they come in a little different package.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal and will get even worse with time.

As this site matures, it gets filled with all the questions and answers. Even now it provides a pretty complete manual covering almost anything you might encounter with Blender. This is because old questions are still relevant for new Blender releases.

Users that know how to search will likely find a solution, the problem is not that there is not enough information anymore as the site gets filled with it every day.

Because of this it is more likely to have low quality questions now, it got to the point that cegaton had to [write this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this), which some would consider common knowledge.

Low quality questions generate low interest, low votes and low views. They also make spotting good quality ones harder between them.