# Policy on posting code / error message etc as images

Tags: discussion

For many of the reasons well outlined here

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/5317130

it is stackoverflow policy to post code and error messages as text.

[StackOverflow Help Center: How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

> **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for
> diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible
> to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the
> Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a
> question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Is the same policy relevant here?

http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Yes, I believe this is very much relevant. People with visual impairments will have a hard time when encountering such posts and even those of us that are able to view the images fine it would require a much greater effort. For instance questions about Python scripts would require to recreate the code. I've also seen screenshots of error messages where relevant parts are cut-off because the terminal doesn't show everything at once etc.

Comment: @batFINGER maybe it would help if you write something on this topic on the [canned comments](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/622/pre-canned-comments-to-help-users)

Comment: Totally agree, worth a canned response too.

Comment: I think the correct thing to do is to let the user know what the problem is.
A down-vote with a comment explaining what is wrong might get the attention of the user. But the comment should also explain how to fix it.

Comment: .... wouldn't bother downvoting, the dv link in q came up in a search thought I'd post it.  When I've requested a user to _"please post code as text"_ some responses sure get the mouse hovering over the DV button tho...  Re canned comment will look to how  SO  has phrased it in how to ask question page. Link escapes me atm.

Comment: I agree with this.* However* error messages in blender often are popup boxes under the mouse that disappear. I expect a lot of users do not know how to get the text of such an error message. Now about images of text, you could broaden this to say something along the lines of "no text in images." Sure a screen shot of blender will have text (and thats fine) but when someone opens up paint and adds what should be the answer to the image, now thats a problem. Same as screenshot of code it is near useless.